# How to add tool-tip in d3 group chart using csv file

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

js charts I want to show tool-tip on my chart. I dont know how to add it. can any one tell me how to add tool-tip on my chart.

here i have add my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 Example</title>
    <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="d3-legend.js"></script>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
    body { font: 12px Arial;}

    path { 
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 2;
        fill: none;
    }
      .axis text {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 12pt;
      }
      .axis .label {
        font-size: 20pt;
      }

      .axis path, .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
      }

      .color-legend text {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 12pt;
      }

rect:hover {
                fill: #3EBCE6;
            }
rect {
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
   transition: all 0.3s;
}


    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var outerWidth = 1200;
      var outerHeight = 720;
      var margin = { left: 90, top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 40 };
      var barPadding = 0.2;

      var xColumn = "Building";
      var yColumn = "Total";
      var colorColumn = "Type";
      var layerColumn = colorColumn;

      var innerWidth  = outerWidth  - margin.left - margin.right;
      var innerHeight = outerHeight - margin.top  - margin.bottom;
debugger;
      var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width",  outerWidth+500)
        .attr("height", outerHeight+150);
      var g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
      var xAxisG = g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerHeight + ")");
      var yAxisG = g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis");
      var colorLegendG = g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "color-legend")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+(outerWidth )+", 0)");

      var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, innerWidth], barPadding);
      var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([innerHeight, 0]);
      var colorScale = d3.scale.category10();

      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom")
        .outerTickSize(0);
      var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left")
        .ticks(7)
        .tickFormat(d3.format("s"))
        .outerTickSize(0);

      var colorLegend = d3.legend.color()
        .scale(colorScale)
        .shapePadding(2)
        .shapeWidth(15)
        .shapeHeight(15)
        .labelOffset(4);

      function render(data){

        var nested = d3.nest()
          .key(function (d){ return d[layerColumn]; })
          .entries(data)

        var stack = d3.layout.stack()
          .y(function (d){ return d[yColumn]; })
          .values(function (d){ return d.values; });

        var layers = stack(nested);

        xScale.domain(layers[0].values.map(function (d){
          return d[xColumn];
        }));

        yScale.domain([
          0,
          d3.max(layers, function (layer){
            return d3.max(layer.values, function (d){
              return d.y;
            });
          })
        ]);

        colorScale.domain(layers.map(function (layer){
          return layer.key;
        }));

        xAxisG.call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")  
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", "-.5em")
            .attr("dy", "-.0em")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "rotate(-45)" 
                });
        yAxisG.call(yAxis);

        var layers = g.selectAll(".layer").data(layers);
        layers.enter().append("g").attr("class", "layer");
        layers.exit().remove();
        layers.style("fill", function (d){
          return colorScale(d.key);
        });

        var bars = layers.selectAll("rect").data(function (d){
          return d.values;
        });
        var barWidth = xScale.rangeBand() / colorScale.domain().length;
        bars.enter()
        .append("rect")
        bars.exit().remove();
        bars
          .attr("x", function (d, i, j){
            return xScale(d[xColumn]) + barWidth * j;
          })
          .attr("y", function (d){ return yScale(d.y); })
          .attr("width", barWidth)
          .attr("height", function (d){ return innerHeight - yScale(d.y); })


               .append("title")
   .text(function(d) {
         return d.VALUE;
         });
        colorLegendG.call(colorLegend);
      }

      function type(d){
        d.Total = +d.Total;
        return d;
      }

      d3.csv("D3.csv", type, render);



// Define the div for the tooltip


    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

here is my csv file

```
Building,Type,Small,Medium,Large,Total
Building1,Food,68,38,40,146
Building1,Medicine,24,38,24,86
Building2,Food,31,24,40,95
Building2,Medicine,17,38,22,77
Building3,Food,24,24,22,70
Building3,Medicine,27,38,40,105
Building4,Food,23,38,24,85
Building4,Medicine,20,38,22,80
Building5,Food,17,24,40,81
Building5,Medicine,40,38,22,100
Building6,Food,68,38,40,146
Building6,Medicine,24,38,24,86
Building7,Food,31,24,40,95
Building7,Medicine,17,38,22,77
Building8,Food,24,24,22,70
Building8,Medicine,27,38,40,105
Building9,Food,23,38,24,85
Building9,Medicine,20,38,22,80
Building10,Food,17,24,40,81
Building10,Medicine,40,38,22,100
Building11,Food,17,24,40,81
Building11,Medicine,40,38,22,100
Building12,Food,68,38,40,146
Building12,Medicine,24,38,24,86
Building13,Food,31,24,40,95
Building13,Medicine,17,38,22,77
Building14,Food,24,24,22,70
Building14,Medicine,27,38,40,105
Building15,Food,23,38,24,85
Building15,Medicine,20,38,22,80
Building16,Food,17,24,40,81
Building16,Medicine,40,38,22,100
Building17,Food,17,24,40,81
Building17,Medicine,40,38,22,100
```

I have upload my both d3 js code and csv file code.  can any one tell me how to add tooltip.

Thanks

Vinoth

Answer (score 0):

I have add the following code to my code:

```
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
```

style

```
 .d3-tip {
      line-height: 1;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 12px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 2px;
    }

    /* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
    .d3-tip:after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: inline;
      font-size: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 1;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      content: "\25BC";
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
    }

    /* Style northward tooltips differently */
    .d3-tip.n:after {
      margin: -1px 0 0 0;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
    }
```

script

```
 width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Type:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.Type + "</span><br>" +
    "<strong>Small:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.Small + "</span><br>"+
    "<strong>Medium:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.Medium + "</span><br>"+
    "<strong>Large:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.Large + "</span><br>";

  })

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);

 bars
          .attr("x", function (d, i, j){
            return xScale(d[xColumn]) + barWidth * j;
          })
          .attr("y", function (d){ return yScale(d.y); })
          .attr("width", barWidth)
          .attr("height", function (d){ return innerHeight - yScale(d.y); })
           .on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide)

               .append("title")
   .text(function(d) {
         return d.VALUE;
         });
```

Comment: but small probalem for this is tool tip is shown on top of the bar.